# auto-generate code for delegation/encapsulation class (in Intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My problem:

I have:

```
public class Bla {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("blaNative");
    }
    public static native T3 method1(T1 p1, T2 p2);
    public static native T6 method2(T4 p4, T5 p5);
    ...
    hundreds of other native methods here
    ...
}
```

I want to automatically generate:

```
public class BlaWrapper implements BlaInterface {

    public T3 method1(T1 p1, T2 p2) {
        return Bla.method1(p1,p2);
    }
    public T6 method2(T4 p4, T5 p5) {
        return Bla.method2(p4,p5);
    }
    ...
    hundreds of other methods here
    ...
}
    
public interface BlaInterface {
    public T3 method1(T1 p1, T2 p2);
    public T6 method2(T4 p4, T5 p5);
    ...
    hundreds of other methods here
    ...
}
```

Note: generating the BlaInterface is straightforward.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and your expertise

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case someone else bumps into the same kind of issue:

spoiler alert: the secret sauce is the "Code->Override Methods" in the intellij menu:

1. temporarily remove "static" keyword from Bla class
2. create an empty BlaWraper child class extending Bla
3. in Intellij menu select "Code->Override Methods", that will automatically  insert a delegation call to the parent class...Hurray !!
4. you're now just a few "find and replace" away for finishing:
   a) in the overriding method replace　"super." with "Bla."
   b) reintroduce "static" keyword in parent class
   c) replace "extends Bla" with "implements BlaInterface" in BlaWrapper

Et voila ! :-)